# Habilitación del atributo disabled mediante script

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, script

**Hola de nuevo grandiosa comunidad :D**

Lo que pasa es que tengo 3 input con id y name:

1. mb_adicional
2. precio_mb_adicional y
3. precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago

Y necesito que el input 2 y 3 estén deshabilitados en un principio, solo al escribir en el 1ro los otros dos cambien a habilitados.
Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#precio_mb_adicional').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').attr("disabled", true);

        $('#mb_adicional').onkeyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value.length == 1) {
                $('#precio_mb_adicional').val('');
                $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').val('');
                $('#precio_mb_adicional').attr("disabled", true);
                $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else
                $('#precio_mb_adicional').removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pero al escribir en el 1ro no se habilitan los otros dos.... ya le di muchas vueltas y no se por que no lo puedo lograrlo.... Help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas remover el atributo `disabled` del elemento para que se habilite al usuario, solo debes cambiar su valor a false, estabas muy cerca de lograrlo.

Además he mejorado un poco tu condición para que siempre estén deshabilitados los `input` si el valor del primer `input` contiene menos de 2 caracteres.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#precio_mb_adicional').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').attr("disabled", true);

    $('#mb_adicional').keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        
        if (value.length <= 1) {
            $('#precio_mb_adicional').val('');
            $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').val('');
            $('#precio_mb_adicional').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').attr("disabled", true);
        }else{
            $('#precio_mb_adicional').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="mb_adicional" id="mb_adicional">
<input type="text" name="precio_mb_adicional" id="precio_mb_adicional">
<input type="text" name="precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago" id="precio_mb_adicional_pronto_pago">
```

Comment: Mil gracias, muy cierto... estaba a punto, pero me traiciono la lógica :P Solo que lo baje a que fuera uno, ya que este si depende de que solo sea una cantidad mínima, pero aun así, gracias y excelente trabajo.

Comment: @Dante oh se me olvidaba, para cambiar valores de atributos no necesitas usar .prop() este lo usas para cambiar valores de propiedades, saludos!